# Getting started with Android Studio: configuration issues

Tags: android, windows

So, I've just downloaded the Studio and tried to run a blank app. It's built all right, but when I try to run it, an error running Java occurs
Also, there is a couple of corrupt packages in the SDK. Is it okay? If not, how to fix it?
Everything is on the screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must change in build.gradle file string: buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc1" to buildToolsVersion "22.0.1".

Answer (score 0):

Okay, everything seems to be fixed

Corrupt packages: there was another component missing, it fixed the detection of RC channel

AVD: as usual, set RAM to 768MB. Unusual (relative to Eclipse): looks like now there is two sets of AVD images, for Studio and for ADT and those in SDK manager are quite useless. Anyway, that's just an assumption - ADT and Studio are both quite unfamiliar to me